# Splitting a tensorflow graph into subgraphs

Tags: python, tensorflow, graph

I've been trying to split an existing Tensorflow graph into multiple subgraphs (to run in a distributed system) 
For eg. given a graph of a neural network - split it layer-wise into multiple graphs. (so passing the output from one subgraph to the next would be equivalent to running the original graph)

I've tried converting it into a graph def and using extract_sub_graphs but I lose the session and it doesn't take an argument for input specification.

I'm not sure if it's possible to create subgraphs using the tf graph_editor if yes, I would really appreciate an example.

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you ever make any more progress on this? I'm trying to do the same thing, and the sheer lack of available information is astonishing.

Comment: I have moved to pytorch since then